# Opening an activity from a fragment using a button

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am completely new to android studio (kotlin) and am attempting to open a new activity from a fragment using a button. I apologize if this is simple, i just can not seem to figure it out.

This is what i have so far, it does not do anything when i run the emulator and click on the button

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val btntakepicture: Button? = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_take_picture)
        btntakepicture?.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().run {
                startActivity(Intent(this, takepicture::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no reason to ever override `onCreate` in a fragment. It is called before your view is created so you have no button to set a listener on at that point. You should override `onViewCreated` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can move the code to the **onViewCreated** method instead, which is called after the view is created:

Answer (score 0):

Override `onViewCreated` method as follow:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    val btntakepicture: Button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_take_picture)
    btntakepicture.setOnClickListener {
        requireActivity().run {
            startActivity(Intent(this, takepicture::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```